# Render single icon on hover using map - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I trying show the value (index + 1) for default and onMouseOver at tr want to change the default value to PlayCircleOutlineIcon but using ReactHooks, I just found with Class. The way i'm doing all the items in map are changing at same time.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";
import PlayCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayCircleOutline";
import PauseCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PauseCircleOutline";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";


const List = () => {
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

  let chartURL = `https://api.deezer.com/chart/0/tracks?&limit=10`;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(chartURL).then((res) => {
      setDataList(res.data.data);
    });
  }, [valueList]);
  return (
    <>
      <Table>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {dataList.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <tr 
                    key={index}
                    onMouseOver={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget)}
                  >
                    <td>
                      {/* <PlayCircleOutlineIcon /> */}
                      {/* <PauseCircleOutlineIcon /> */}
                      {index + 1}
                    </td>               
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </Table>
      ;
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Thank You!!

Comment: So, where is the code for changing the icon on hover???

Comment: @Shuvo thank you for the reply, I was thinking a lot about how to accomplish this and then, figured out could be like my answer below. (sorry for my english is not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i got what i expected using this code, onMouseEnter and render the Obj, after, onMouseLeave the parent element changing again to {index+1}

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";
import PlayCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayCircleOutline";
import PauseCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PauseCircleOutline";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";


const List = () => {
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

  let chartURL = `https://api.deezer.com/chart/0/tracks?&limit=10`;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(chartURL).then((res) => {
      setDataList(res.data.data);
    });
  }, [valueList]);
  return (
    <>
      <Table>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {dataList.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <tr 
                    key={index}
                    onMouseEnter={(e) =>
                      (e.currentTarget.firstElementChild.innerHTML =
                        ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                          <PlayCircleOutlineIcon />
                        ))
                    }
                    onMouseLeave={(e) =>
                      (e.currentTarget.firstElementChild.innerHTML = index + 1)
                    }
                  >
                    <td>
                      {index + 1}
                    </td>               
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </Table>
      ;
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just writing here because it may be useful for someone in the future.

It's from this question here: [onClick event not working on icon displayed on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041595/onclick-event-not-working-on-icon-displayed-on-hover)

As adsy wrote on that post:

> What you are attempting to do is quite odd and not the way you go
> about this. You should never call ReactDOMServer.renderToString inside
> a component -- this is set up basically a whole new react tree
> disconnected from your existing one. Also, setting innerHTML of
> anything that's owned by React is not allowed, as it's react-owned DOM
> and this is an imperative call to change the DOM that is effectively
> outside of Reacts constructs, which just won't work.
>
> Two options:
>
> 1. Make it so onMouseEnter, the ID of the row is stored in some state,
>    and then in the render of the rows, for the row that matches that ID
>    -- we render the icons.
> 2. Always render the buttons into the DOM for every row, but use CSS to
>    display/hide them on hover.
>
> Option 2 is
> almost certainly better, as you don't need to manage the state
> unnecessarily when it is known to CSS. Additionally, it will feel more
> performant as you go up and down the rows since you won't have
> re-renders happening as the user moves the mouse.